# Sharepoint 2007 - .mht files do not show up in search results

Tags: search, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have a bunch of .mht files in the document library and they don't seem to be indexed.

I have checked - **.mht is in the File Types list** in Central Sdmin -> SSP and also there's an entry for it in the **DOCICON.xml**.

But .mht files are still either not being indexed or do not show up in the search.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not indexed as in no search works for thier content or they do not appear when you search on properties and/or title.

Comment: Check the crawl log to see if they are crawled first.

Comment: I suggested a few tests but ended up coming across a KB I reminded we had to use to crawl another extension. That should do it

Answer (score 0):

Use this [Microsoft KB](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/826789)

> To add an .mht extension mapping,
>   follow these steps:
>
> 1. Log on to
>      the SQL server that Windows SharePoint
>      Services 2.0 uses as its database
>      server.
> 2. Click Start, click
>      Run,
>      type regedit, and
>      then click OK.
> 3. Locate, and then click the following registry
>      subkey:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ContentIndexCommon\Filters\Extension
> 4. Right-click
>      the Extension
>      registry key, point to New, and then
>      click Key.
> 5. Type .mht to name
>      the new key.
>    **Note** There
>      is a period (**.**) in front of
>      "mht".
> 6. Click the
>      .mht
>      registry key.
> 7. In the right
>      pane, right-click (Default), and
>      then click Modify.
> 8. In the Value data
>      box, type the following line, and then
>      click OK:{5645C8C2-E277-11CF-8FDA-00AA00A14F93}
>    **Note** This registry
>      value contains zeros, not the letter
>      O.
> 9. Quit Registry
>      Editor, and then restart the Microsoft
>      Search service (MSSearch). To restart
>      this service:
>
>      Click
>        Start,
>        click Run, type
>        services.msc
>        in the Open box, and
>        then click OK.
>   In the Name list,
>     click Microsoft
>     Search, and then click the
>     Restart
>     link.